# LinearLayout - making the first child width based on the second

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to add a horizontal `LinearLayout` programmatically, making sure the second child

takes all the width it needs and the first child will take all the space left.

I don't have a code to add, because I try many options, and nothing worked yet.

any idea?

Comment: give the waight 1 to  second child chlid

Comment: what weight to give to the first? and what to put on the LayoutParams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `android:layout_weight="0"` for second child. And for first child set `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Comment: and what to put on the LayoutParams?

Comment: TextView tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
__The last parameter is the weight.__

Answer (score -1):

try this change the text of button3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Read sad s as d" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you noticed this word **programmatically**?

Comment: but may be after this he may net need to change the in java code ..as per button text other button width get reduce.......

Comment: I need programmatically and I want to make sure that the second child is visible and not the first one

Comment: This is not the correct answer for this question... We can't predict user thoughts right?

Comment: @Venky see the almost same logic worked ..... and if you ever worked on android then you will have idea that it is not difficult to set layout params in code.......so It would be better if you  noitced the word programmatically (which i not as i think writing  layout Xml is also the part of programming ) suggest the answer instead of pointing the mistake.